# Blind, can't hear when battery is low?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro. I'm legally blind and usually don't see the popup that says the battery is low.

Is there a way to make it give me an audio alert?

I've heard that you can do this with Voiceover, but I can't find any options for it. If there's a way to do it without voiceover, that would be even better.

Thank you!

Comment: There's an app called [Battery Box](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/battery-box/id1144921017?mt=12) that might do the trick for you!

Answer (score 2):

this can be done using Apple Script after I did slight research.
Actually I cannot help you with it, because I am not experience in apple scripting, but if some would like to try, here is advisory:

[Give your mac a more attention grabbing low battery warning](http://lifehacker.com/5769174/give-your-mac-a-more-attention-grabbing-low-battery-warning)

Comment: Related to this: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110219013713667